# Laravel 5 - Get Auth User

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am using Laravel 5 and I have installed the Brainsocket package in it.

The Vendor folder it has this structure:

```
 vendor/brainboxlabs/brain-socket/src/brainsocket
```

and this code in /brainSocketeventlistner.php

```
public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
    var_dump(Auth::user()); // Returns Null
    echo "Connection Established! \n";
    $this->clients->attach($conn);

    connections::create([
        'user_id'       => '3232',
        'connection_id' => $conn->resourceId
    ]);
```

I am using two `use` calls:

```
use Auth;
use App\Connections;
```

I can access App\connections 
but I can't access Auth to get logged in user data.

Comment: Are you sure the user is logged in? `Auth::user()` returns `null` if no user is logged in.

Answer (score 0):

```
use Auth
```

is enough for using laravel Auth , check if your user is really logged in by

```
Auth::check()
```

Answer (score 0):

If the user has to be logged in to access which ever bit of code is calling that function, you might want to protect the route using the out of the box Authenticate Middleware